# How to check object before adding 'inline = []' in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I don't know how to make one customization in my Django admin panel.

For example I have table `test` and another table `testinfo`. I know how to make `admin.TabularInline` of `testinfo` table in `test` table. But how to check, for example, if `id` of `test` table is bigger than 3, to show `TabularInline`, if not to not show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelAdmin` has [a method called `get_inline_instances()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_inline_instances) that can be used to achieve this effect.

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj.id > 3:
            self.inlines = [TestInfoInline, ]
        else:
            self.inlines = []
        return super(TestAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)
```

Second example - the effect remains exactly the same:

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines_foo = []
    inlines_bar = [TestInfoInline, ]

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        self.inlines = self.inlines_foo if obj.id <= 3 else self.inlines_bar
        return super(TestAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)
```

Comment: id doesn't work, I always get `unbound method get_formset() must be called with TestInfoInline instance as first argument (got WSGIRequest instance instead)`. What to do?

Comment: Sorry, that was entirely my fault. I updated my answer.

Comment: Again, I am having problems... Every time I refersh page I get 2 new formsets of TestInfoInline

Answer (score 0):

Well I think your problem is related to the issue discussed here [Misleading documentation in ModelAdmin.get_inline_instances](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-updates/2ZLVy-ox958). So essentially your code should be changed to something like...
    # Assuming you have a TestInfoInline inline that inherits from a BaseModelAdmin defined 
    # similarly to below.
    class TestInfoInline(admin.StackedInline):
       # Relevant stuff here...
       ...

```
class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
      inlines = []
      if obj.id > 3:
         for inline_class in self.inlines:
            # Instanciate inline object
            inline = inline_class(self.model, self.admin_site)
            inlines.append(inline)
      return inlines
```

Hope this helps someone...